# How to add Python module in existing Java Application

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine

I have a GAE Java app already deployed which is using Datastore.
Now, I need to split that app in modules and have second module which is written in Python to access that same Datastore.
I cannot find useful info on how to split app in modules in a way that:

- it supports Java in first module and Python in second module
- both modules can access same Datastore (I guess this implies since both are part of same GAE application)

Main question would be: what are steps to do define these two modules with different programming languages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app.yaml` to configure your main (Java) module, as detailed at  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml , and separate `.yaml` files to configure your other (Python, PHP, and/or Go -- or also, some of them could also be Java!-)) modules, as detailed at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Configuration .

As you suspect, all modules always **do** access exactly the same instance of the datastore.

So for example you could have in `app.yaml`...:

```
application: myapp
version: alpha-001
runtime: java
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /myjava/*
  servlet: myapp.myservlets.DoItAllServlet
```

to map all urls `/myjava/something` to that single servlet, and in e.g `mypython.yaml`

```
application: myapp
module: mypython
version: v1
runtime: python27

handlers:
- url: /mypy/*
  script: mypython.app
```

to map all URLs `/mypy/something` to the single WSGI application bound to global variable `app` in module `mypython.py`.  Of course, there are huge numbers of degrees of freedom on both the main ("default") module, and the other ones, I'm just trying to show the very simplest "skeleton" here!-)

Comment: Thank you Alex. Do you know how folder structure should be? For Java in Google documentation they only mention those EAR and War folders. Is that the same folder structure when using yaml approach?

Comment: @BTosic, the URL I quoted says only "This file is stored in the application's WEB-INF directory" about app.yaml itself, so presumably all the rest of the folder structure does not change.